# Show image from binary stream

Tags: ios, swift, stream, uiimage

I want to display an PNG-image I get via binary stream when I send a nullbyte to the server. 
I do get information from the stream. But the image is never shown and I don't know why. Maybe someone sees a mistake.

My code is following:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
NSInputStream *inputStream;
NSOutputStream *outputStream;
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <NSStreamDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *secondView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

- (IBAction)sendNullbyte:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *firstView;

@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSOutputStream *fileStream;

@end
```

and

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self initNetworkCommunication];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)initNetworkCommunication {
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"localhost", 80, &readStream, &writeStream);
    inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
    outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];
    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];
}

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent{
    switch (streamEvent) {
        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            NSLog(@"Stream opened");
            break;
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
            NSLog(@"Has bytes available.");
            //be sure that event comes from input stream
            if(theStream == inputStream){
                UInt8 buffer[500000];
                long len;
                BOOL firstbytes = true;
                 //read method returns 0 when there is nothing left in the stream
                 len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                 if (len > 0){
                     NSData *output = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len-4];
                     if (output != nil){
                         NSLog(@"server said: %@", output);
                         UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:output];;
                         _imageView.image = image;
                     }
                 }
            }

            break;
        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
            NSLog(@"Cant not connect to the host");
            break;
        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (IBAction)sendNullbyte:(id)sender {
    NSInteger nullbyte = 0x00;
    NSData *data =[[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:&nullbyte length:1];
    [outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_secondView];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `unit8_t` instead `UInt8`, and make sure that u handle the case that the image doesn't get to u in a single packet...

U can do something like this:

```
{
  NSMutableData *data; // ivar
}

  // init it somewhere
  data = [NSMutableData new];

case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:

if (theStream == inputStream) {

    uint8_t buffer[5000]; 
    int length;

    while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
        length = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
        if (length > 0) {
            [data appendBytes:(const void *)buffer length];
        }
    }
}
break;

case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
{
    if (theStream == inputStream) {
        UIImage *imagess = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
        [imagesview setImage:imagess];
    }
}   break;
```

Comment: ... i tried it with the uint8_t instead and the while loop - without success

I can not use the case NSStreamEventEndEncountered because the stream remains open...

Comment: Why that? U should get `NSStreamEventEndEncountered`,